# filter data with entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to get the right data

Rooms table

```
Id | Name
1    Room1
2    Room2
```

Resources table

```
Id | Name
1    Resource1
2    Resource2
3    Resource3
```

RoomResources table

```
Id | RoomId | ResourceId
1      1         1
2      1         2
3      1         3
4      2         2
5      2         3
```

I want select a room with Resource1 and Resource2
I'm using this code

```
int[] ids = sResources.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

rooms = from r in context.Rooms
    where r.Area.Office.Id == officeId
    && r.MaximumPeople >= numberOfPeople
    && r.RoomResources.Any(s => ids.Contains(s.ResourceId))
    select r;
```

but it return Room1 and Room2 and the result should be Room1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
int[] ids = sResources.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

rooms = from r in context.Rooms
    where r.Area.Office.Id == officeId
    && r.MaximumPeople >= numberOfPeople
    && ids.All(i => r.RoomResources.Any(s => s.ResourceId == i)) // try this here
    select r;
```